# Using json_encode() and still send array in object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I send AJAX request with ID and I am expecting a response from PHP with additional info. PHP is having a response like this:

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [id] => 20
    [fullname] => John Doe
    [statuslist] => Array
        (
            [1] => Status1
            [2] => Status2
            [3] => Status3
        )

)
```

When I `json_encode()` it

```
return json_encode($response);
```

I get a response like this:

```
{"success":true,"id":"20","fullname":"John Doe","statuslist":{"1":"Status1","2":"Status2","3":"Status3"}}
```

When I `JSON.parse()` in JS, it becomes an object. But also `statuslist` becomes a nested object and that is the problem.

```
let res = JSON.parse(data) /* where data is response from server */
```

When I `console.log(res.statuslist)` I get the following object:

```
{ 1 : "Status1", 2 : "Status2", 3 : "Status3"}
```

What I really want is to get is an object like I already have, but with statuslist being a 2D Array where I will have the output on `console.log(res.statuslist)`:

```
[
    ["1", "Status1"],
    ["2", "Status2"],
    ["3", "Status3"]
]
```

My PHP Array looks like this:

```
$statusList = ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\SomeModel::find()->all(), 'id', 'title');

$response = [
    'success' => true,
    'id' => $id,
    'fullname' => $user->fullname,
    'statuslist' => $statusList,
];
```

Comment: So, modify your `Array` structure in php.

Comment: Show us your php code.

Comment: There are workarounds in javascript where you can restructure your json once you fetched it, however the better approach would be restructuring it in your php code

Comment: @Joseph_J There you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use array_map before json_encode to do the work

```
$arr['statuslist'] = array_map(null, array_keys($arr['statuslist']), $arr['statuslist']);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e19ed1180d4bb3120be8414876b9b153070d4078)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so considering your PHP code as;

```
 $statusList = ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\SomeModel::find()->all(), 'id', 'title');

$response = [
     'success' => true,
     'id' => $id,
     'fullname' => $user->fullname,
     'statuslist' => $statusList,
];
```

From this I am considering `$statusList` is associative array like;

```
 $statusList = Array
 (
        [1] => Status1
        [2] => Status2
        [3] => Status3
 )

 $statusList2d = Array();

 foreach ($statusList as $key => $value) {
    $innerArray = Array();
    array_push($innerArray, $key, $value);

    array_push($statusList2d, $innerArray);
 }

 $response = [
     'success' => true,
     'id' => $id,
     'fullname' => $user->fullname,
     'statuslist' => $statusList2d
 ];
```

Now you can do `json_encode($response)` to get your expected result.

Comment: Aight, this works, but just change the name of variable $2d since it's not a valid name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your initial data:

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [id] => 20
    [fullname] => John Doe
    [statuslist] => Array
        (
            [1] => Status1
            [2] => Status2
            [3] => Status3
        )

)
```

Because `statuslist` indices start with `1` instead of `0`, `json_encode()` doesn't think it's an array and encode it into an object:

```
{ 1 : "Status1", 2 : "Status2", 3 : "Status3"}
```

Start your PHP array with index 0, and it should work.

Comment: It has to start with 1, since that is the value of status.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using javascript (i.e. client side) would be to use the [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method (ECMAScript 2017) on the `statuslist` object to convert it into an array.

```js
//Assume you get the data as a JSON string
let data = '{"success":true,"id":"20","fullname":"John Doe","statuslist":{"1":"Status1","2":"Status2","3":"Status3"}}';
let res = JSON.parse(data);     //parse the string

//Use Object.entries to convert object to an array with [key, value] pairs
res.statuslist = Object.entries(res.statuslist);

console.log(res); //check result
```